# How do I get the service_broker to start up in a vcap dev deployment?

Tags: cloud-foundry

The instructions currently in the [README for the service_broker](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap-services/tree/master/service_broker) talk about setting some environmental variable, but those instructions are obsolete (yes, I'll issue a pull request).

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

**You can edit the deployment and rerun vcap_dev_setup**:

In this case you simply need to edit the .../cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/deployments/devbox.yml file (or whatever deployment file you are using) and add service_broker to the list of jobs:

```
---
deployment:
  name: "devbox"

jobs:
  install:
    - nats_server

    ... snip a bunch of other jobs ...

    - service_broker
```

and then rerun vcap_dev_setup.

But this takes a bit of time so the quicker solution if you already have vcap dev deployed is to...

**Update your existing deployment**

To do this, go into ...cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config directory do two things:

1. edit the vcap_components.json file adding "service_broker"
2. drop a service_broker.yml file into that same directory

You can find a sample of the service_broker.yml in the ...cloudfoundry/vcap/services/service_broker/config directory - just make sure to set the values of the token, cloud_controller_uri, mbus, pid and local_db right - have a look at one of the other .yml files in the ...cloudfoundry/.deployments/devbox/config for examples.